# Centralised Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, azure, remote-access

I need solution for Centralized DB.

We have DB in one Hosting server (Azure Redhat virtual server) and we need to use the same db in other hosting server too. So it will be centralized DB for both server. I can not use it in navicat also if I use IP of Mysql DB.

I have tried using ( bind-address= IP address of the server where db is hosted ) in My.cnf file but it doesn't allow remote access. to use it in other hosting server nor in any mysql client like navicat / Heidi sql.

Also I have added the port 3306 rule in azure server for inbound security.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831553/using-a-central-database-server-for-many-sites-plausible

Comment: Hello Channasmcs, Thanks for reply but the thread shows more generailised reply. I need the solution with linux commands and configuration wise. I tried using telnet IP 3306 but got connection time out error so it looks more firewall issue.

Comment: Hi @user1648204, do you have any update now?

Comment: Yes, The issue has been resolved using https://ahmedzubayr.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/configure-master-slave-replication-mysql-xampp/

Answer (score 0):

As Azure VMs disable ICMP and we can use SSH tunnels to allow outside access to internal network resources.

Please try to follow this [post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-your-own-dedicated-mysql-server-for-your-azure-websites/), created a SSH tunnel in VM which hosted the MySQL server:

- Open port 3306, so a remote client can connect to your MySQL Server. Run the following command to open TCP port 3306

  `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

  Now let’s check if the port 3306 is open by running this command:

  `sudo netstat -anltp|grep :3306`
- Create a SSH tunnel for port 3307

  `sudo ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 azurevmuser@servername`
- Create an endpoint for the port 3307 rule in azure server for inbound security. Now your Database host name is `<VM_ip>:3307`

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.